# Meteor MapReduce Package Error: A method named is already defined

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

Trying to use the [`monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation`](https://github.com/monbro/meteor-mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation/) to run a super simple mapReduce function. While it works great the first time around, subsequent calls I get the following error:

```
I20150608-11:11:05.294(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'exportDonations' Error: A method named '/donation_totals_by_donor/insert' is already defined
I20150608-11:11:05.294(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461:1
I20150608-11:11:05.294(-4)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
I20150608-11:11:05.294(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1459:1)
I20150608-11:11:05.294(-4)?     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:904:1)
I20150608-11:11:05.294(-4)?     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:209:1)
I20150608-11:11:05.295(-4)?     at [object Object].ns.Collection (packages/matb33:collection-hooks/collection-hooks.js:190:1)
I20150608-11:11:05.295(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.exportDonations (app/server/index.js:44:19)
I20150608-11:11:05.295(-4)?     at [object Object].methodMap.(anonymous function) (packages/meteorhacks:kadira/lib/hijack/wrap_session.js:160:1)
I20150608-11:11:05.295(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150608-11:11:05.295(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
```

Here's my Meteor method:

```
var Reduced = new Mongo.Collection("donation_totals_by_donor");

    var map = function() {
      if(!this.donor) {
        return;
      }

      emit(this.donor, this.amount);
    }

    var reduce = function(donorId, totalAmount) {
      return Array.sum(totalAmount);
    }

    var result = Donations.mapReduce(
                  map,
                  reduce,
                  {
                    query: { createdAt: { $gte: new Date('Jan 1, ' + year), $lt: new Date('Jan 1, ' + (year + 1)) } },
                    out: "donation_totals_by_donor",
                    verbose: true
                  }
                 );

    return Reduced.find({}).fetch();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is the result of defining your collection multiple times. You need to move the `new Mongo.Collection` code outside of the method.

Typically you'd define your collections in a central location, e.g. `lib/collections/mycollection.js`. However, because this code is only running on the server you could just keep it at the top of this file or put it somewhere like `server/collections/reduced.js`.

Comment: Nailed it on the head. Just had to move it outside of the method and all is working exactly as expected. Thank you! Will mark as answer in 10 minutes when SO lets me.